# How to attach functions together in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, observable

I am having a hard time understanding this piece of code:

```
public IObservable<SomeInfo> OriginalFunction() => FirstFunction().SecondFunction(argument1).ThirdFunction(argument2);
```

First, I don't understand what that `IObservable<CarsInfo>` means. Does this function return an observable?

Then, what does the lambda `=>` do?

And finally, how are the three functions attached to each other using dots?

Comment: First returns a result on which Second is called, which returns a result on which Third is called which returns IObservable<SomeInfo>. `=>` is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: For the chaining part look at Builder pattern

Comment: `=>` means code inside the method, but in lambda.

and `IObserable<CarsInfo>` usually it should be generic interface

Comment: @Muaath - What does "usually it should be generic interface" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I mean: there is tradition: any type start with capital `I` means it's an interface, Not class or enum.
and any type contains `<>` means it's generic

Comment: @Muaath - Yes, that's what it already is. Why did you mention it? What was the point you're trying to make?

Answer (score 3):

```
public IObservable<SomeInfo> OriginalFunction() => FirstFunction().SecondFunction(argument1).ThirdFunction(argument2);
```

is equivalent to

```
public IObservable<SomeInfo> OriginalFunction() 
{ 
    var firstResult = FirstFunction();
    var secondResult = firstResult.SecondFunction(argument1)
    return secondResult.ThirdFunction(argument2); // mind the 'return' here!
}
```

which by the way expect `argument1` and `argument2` as class fields or properties, which some people would consider "not so clean"*.

* I should elaborate on that: While clean code advocates for having as small number of arguments as possible, using class fields or properties here does make the function harder to test. I personally would consider this  a kind of side-effect which should be avoided. What do I mean by side-effect? Two calls of this function may return different results depending on the value of class fields. *This **could** be reasonable* or not. Depends on the actual semantics of the code which is not at all clear from the example.

So, TL;DR: Consider if it is reasonable to use class fields or if it is more reasonable to to use two arguments or use an "Options-Pattern" argument. Take into account: Is it clear what result to expect ("do not surprise clients")? Is the function testable? And some more...

---

EDIT:

`=>` is a feature added in C# 6.0 : [Expression-bodied function members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied-function-members)

> Many members that you write are single statements that could be single expressions. Write an expression-bodied member instead. It works for methods and read-only properties. For example, an override of ToString() is often a great candidate:
> `public override string ToString() => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";`

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question: I tried to replace the => with curly brackets, but now I get the "Not all code paths return a value" error.

Comment: @coyob49 it's another syntactic sugar from c# 8 I believe. It's the same as method returning, just shorter syntax. So, `MyMethod{ return 1;}` and `MyMethod => 1;` are equivalent. That's why when you just replace `=>` with curly you gotta add a `return`